# Customize New Comment

Tags: vba, excel

How to create New Comments without "Author:" inserted (vba).
Inherently New Comments are created with the application Author "Author:" inserted. Generally one could replace the author name using.
Application.Author = "Mr.Dud" however to customize this for different uses a different 
    Activecell.AddComment
calls must be added

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub MyComment(strText as String)
' Creates comment applying "strText" to Text

        ActiveCell.AddComment.Text Text:=strText

End Sub
```

---

Then, to create & edit a new comment insert this call to MyComment.
This one inserts the system date and a linefeed;

```
    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        MyComment CStr(Date) & Chr(10)
    End If

    Application.SendKeys ("+{F2}") , True
```

Alternately, MyComment "" could be called if a blank comment is required.

Shortcut keys open comment for editing (instead of Mso:ReviewEditComment call).

Comment: Should you get errors as the Ribbon Refreshes add the following;

Comment: While ActiveCell.Comment.Visible <> False

Comment: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Comment: Wend    ' that should do it